# No instance for (RealFrac Int) arising from a use of ' ... '

Tags: haskell, types, functional-programming

The following program is supposed to check whether the input n is divisible by the sum of digits in n

```
module Harshad where

isHarshad :: Int -> Bool
isHarshad n = (mod n (sumDig n)) == 0)
 where 
  sumDig n 
   | (floor (n / 10) == 0) = n -- n consists of only one digit
   | otherwise = sumDig (floor (n / 10)) + floor (10*(n - floor (n / 10)))
```

I get the following compile error : 
* No instance for (RealFrac Int) arising from a use of `sumDig'

even after trying to add various conversions I'm still stuck.

Comment: What type is `sumDig` supposed to have?

Comment: an Int I suppose

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Drop the fractionals altogether and use only [`div`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:div) for integer division:

```
sumDig n = if n < 10 then n -- n consists of only one digit
           else sumDig (n `div` 10) + (n `mod` 10)
```

Comment: This `div` function, does it `floor`, `ceiling` or `round`? How to change this behaviour?

Comment: @SimonBaars From the linked documentation, "*integer division truncated toward negative infinity*"